# Event though my Braintree transaction is successful, there's no redirect to success page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-3, braintree

I'm struggling with a piece of code for more than a week.
I implemented Braintree, using the PHP SDK, in my Codeigniter app and I have this issue:

1. The user selects the product he wants, enters the shipping method then the Credit Card info;
2. The Credit Card is processed on the Braintree servers and returns a success or error flag;
3. If successful the order is added in the Database and a confirmation email is sent both to the merchant and the customer
4. Finally, the user is redirected to the success page or the error page if the transaction failed.

Everything works as expected in sandbox mode but when I go into production mode, the redirect fails, the page is redirected back to the order confirmation, even though the CC was charged and both emails sent.

Here is my controller:

```
function order_confirmation()
{
    require_once('application/libraries/braintree/lib/Braintree.php');

    Braintree_Configuration::environment('production');
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('MY_MERCHANT_ID');
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('MY_PUBLIC_KEY');
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('MY_PRIVATE_KEY');

    if ($this->input->post('checkout'))
    {   
        $price = 24.99;
        $quantity = 1;  

        if ($this->input->post('shipping') == 1)
            $shipping_price = 0;
        elseif ($this->input->post('shipping') == 2)
            $shipping_price = 6.99;

        $amount = $price * $quantity + $shipping_price;

        //BrainTree payment process
        $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'creditCard' => array(
                'number' => $this->input->post('credit_card_number'),
                'expirationDate' => $this->input->post('expiration_month') . '/' . $this->input->post('expiration_year'),
                'cvv' => $this->input->post('cvv')
            ),          
            'options' => [
                'submitForSettlement' => True
            ]
        ));

        if ($result->success)
        {   
            // I left only the first and last name field to save up space
            $first_name = $this->db->escape($this->session->userdata('first_name'));
            $last_name = $this->db->escape($this->session->userdata('last_name'));                          
            $date_created = $this->db->escape(time());

            // Add the order
            $this->shop_model->add_order($first_name, $last_name, $transaction_id, $date_created);

            $order_id = $this->db->insert_id();

            $product_id = $this->db->escape($this->input->post('product_id'));

            // Add the order items
            $this->shop_model->add_order_items($order_id, $product_id, $quantity, $price);          

            $data['site_name'] = $this->config->item('website_name');
            $data['order'] = $this->shop_model->get_order($order_id);
            $data['order_items'] = $this->shop_model->get_order_items($order_id);

            $customer_email = $this->session->userdata('email');

            // Send the email notification to the merchant
            send_html_email('order_confirmation_merchant', $this->config->item('primary_email'), $this->config->item('website_name'), $this->config->item('primary_email'), 'shop', $data);

            // Send the order confirmation to the customer
            send_html_email('order_confirmation_customer', $this->config->item('primary_email'), $this->config->item('website_name'), $customer_email,  'shop', $data);     

            redirect(SHOP . '/checkout-success');
            // header("Location: checkout-success");                            
            // echo '<script language="JavaScript">document.location.href="' . base_url() . SHOP . '/checkout-success' . '"</script>' . "\n";
        }
        else
        {           
            redirect(SHOP . '/checkout-error');
        }
    }

    $this->template->set_template('no_sidebar');

    $this->template->write('meta_description', 'Order confirmation');
    $this->template->write('meta_keywords', 'Order confirmation');
    $this->template->write('title', 'Order confirmation');
    $this->template->write_view('header', 'frontend/header');
    $this->template->write_view('section', 'frontend/shop/order_confirmation'/*, $data*/);
    $this->template->write_view('footer', 'frontend/footer');
    $this->template->render();  
}
```

As you can see I tried serveral redirect methods (Codeigniter redirect(), native PHP, Javascript) with no success. As mentioned before, I do see the success page in sandbox mode and the error page if I enter a bogus CC, but no success page, only my order confirmation form, in production mode, even though the CC is charged, the order added in the database and the emails sent.

I would like to mention that the website has a SSL certificate and I tested using Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge. There are no JS errors, no PHP warnings.

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `when [you] go into production mode`? Is it just changing your Braintree credentials or something more?

Comment: Hi Raymond and thank you for your answer! The credentials stay the same (in production mode) thus the Credit Card is charged. The only thing not working is the redirect to the success page. I tried on a different server, without SSL and it worked just fine. I know I can't leave the page unsecured but I'm tring to figure out if the server is the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: I take your response to mean that you are changing your CodeIgniter environment to `production mode` but you are still running against the Braintree sandbox with the same credentials. It does sound like a problem with some underlying environment incompatibility. I would recommend contacting [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) to talk about specific problems with your application server if you don't find answers from the CodeIgniter community.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have been unclear. The Codeigniter environment has not been changed, only the Braintree one. While in Braintree sandbox mode, I am redirected to the success page but on Braintree production mode, with the credentials changed, I'm redirected to the same page, the order confirmation. Thanks again for your answer!